# Issue using struct.pack and struct.unpack

Tags: python, object, struct, pack, unpack

Here is my code snippet:

```
import struct


class _packet:

    def __init__(self, payload):  
        self.version = 1
        self.syn = False
        self.fin = False
        self.reset = False
        self.hasOpt = False
        self.ack = 0
        self.payload = payload
        return

    def pack(self):
        return struct.pack('????i' + str(len(self.payload)) + 's', self.syn, self.fin, self.reset, self.hasOpt,self.ack, bytes(self.payload, 'utf-8'))

    def unpack(self):
        unpackedData = bytearray()
        return struct.unpack('????i5s', unpackedData)

def main():
    packet = _packet("Hello")
    packet.ack = 249
    packet.syn = True
    packet.fin = True
    packet.reset = True
    packedData = packet.pack()
    print(packedData)
    unpackedData = packet.unpack()
    print(unpackedData)

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

My goal is to create a packet, use struct.pack to encode it and send it over a socket, and then use unpack to put the data back into a tuple so that I can extract the necessary bits from it. My packet doesn't have some of the needed bits because it's a minimal example of using packets. Once I execute the line

```
packedData = packet.pack()
print(packedData)
```

I receive this as my output:

```
b'\x01\x01\x01\x00\xf9\x00\x00\x00Hello'
```

This seems to be what I expect, but the issue arises when i run the following lines:

```
 unpackedData = packet.unpack()
 print(unpackedData)
```

I get the following error:

```
unpack requires a bytes object of length 13
```

If I change unpacked data to be a bytearray of length 13, I get the following output as my unpacked data:

```
(False, False, False, False, 0, b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
```

This is obviously wrong since it didn't keep my values and just seems to be a different packet instance.

Am I creating my packet objects incorrectly? Or am I packing and unpacking my data incorrectly?

Comment: The formats in `pack` and `unpack` should be the same. If you pack a variable-sized payload, you should unpack the same, not a 5-byte prefix of it.

Comment: `unpack`, presumably, should take a `bytes` object as an argument and return a `_packet` object, not just a tuple of whatever you unpack from the bytes. (And as such, should be a class method, not an instance method.)

Comment: The version should probably be included in the packed version as well. It won't help in the future to unpack a byte string if you don't know what version of `_packet` to create.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want `struct.unpack` to return the data that you passed to `struct.pack`, then the argument you pass to `struct.unpack` must be the object that is returned from `struct.pack`. Right now, you're giving it a blank bytearray, so you're getting back blank data.

One possible solution is to pass the packed data as an argument to `_packet.unpack`, which you then pass to `struct.unpack`.

```
import struct


class _packet:

    def __init__(self, payload):  
        self.version = 1
        self.syn = False
        self.fin = False
        self.reset = False
        self.hasOpt = False
        self.ack = 0
        self.payload = payload
        return

    def pack(self):
        return struct.pack('????i' + str(len(self.payload)) + 's', self.syn, self.fin, self.reset, self.hasOpt,self.ack, bytes(self.payload, 'utf-8'))

    def unpack(self, data):
        header_size = 8 #four one-byte bools and one four-byte int
        return struct.unpack('????i' + str(len(packed_data)-header_size) + 's', data)

def main():
    packet = _packet("Hello")
    packet.ack = 249
    packet.syn = True
    packet.fin = True
    packet.reset = True
    packedData = packet.pack()
    print(packedData)
    unpackedData = packet.unpack(packedData)
    print(unpackedData)

if __name__== "__main__":
  main()
```

Or perhaps you would prefer to assign the packed data as an attribute of the `_packet` instance, so the caller doesn't need to supply any arguments.

```
import struct


class _packet:

    def __init__(self, payload):  
        self.version = 1
        self.syn = False
        self.fin = False
        self.reset = False
        self.hasOpt = False
        self.ack = 0
        self.payload = payload

        self.packed_data = None

    def pack(self):
        self.packed_data = struct.pack('????i' + str(len(self.payload)) + 's', self.syn, self.fin, self.reset, self.hasOpt,self.ack, bytes(self.payload, 'utf-8'))
        return self.packed_data

    def unpack(self):
        header_size = 8 #four one-byte bools and one four-byte int
        return struct.unpack('????i' + str(len(packed_data)-header_size) + 's', self.packed_data)

def main():
    packet = _packet("Hello")
    packet.ack = 249
    packet.syn = True
    packet.fin = True
    packet.reset = True
    packedData = packet.pack()
    print(packedData)
    unpackedData = packet.unpack()
    print(unpackedData)

if __name__== "__main__":
  main()
```

Personally, I would make `unpack` a classmethod, since you shouldn't need to create a _packet instance in order to deserialize some bytes into a new `_packet` object. I would also make the attributes of the object optionally settable during initialization so you don't need to assign to them individually within `main`.

```
import struct


class _packet:

    def __init__(self, payload, **kwargs):  
        self.version = 1
        self.syn = kwargs.get("syn", False)
        self.fin = kwargs.get("fin", False)
        self.reset = kwargs.get("reset", False)
        self.hasOpt = kwargs.get("hasOpt", False)
        self.ack = kwargs.get("ack", 0)
        self.payload = payload

    def pack(self):
        return struct.pack('????i' + str(len(self.payload)) + 's', self.syn, self.fin, self.reset, self.hasOpt,self.ack, bytes(self.payload, 'utf-8'))

    #optional: nice string representation of packet for printing purposes
    def __repr__(self):
        return "_packet(payload={}, syn={}, fin={}, reset={}, hasOpt={}, ack={})".format(self.payload, self.syn, self.fin, self.reset, self.hasOpt, self.ack)

    @classmethod
    def unpack(cls, packed_data):
        header_size = 8 #four one-byte bools and one four-byte int
        syn, fin, reset, hasOpt, ack, payload = struct.unpack('????i' + str(len(packed_data)-header_size) + 's', packed_data)
        return cls(payload, syn=syn, fin=fin, reset=reset, hasOpt=hasOpt, ack=ack)
def main():
    packet = _packet("Hello", ack=249, syn=True, fin=True, reset=True)
    packedData = packet.pack()
    print(packedData)
    unpackedData = _packet.unpack(packedData)
    print(unpackedData)

if __name__== "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: Since `pack` returns a `byte` object, you don't need to pass the (`bytes`-ified) payload as an argument; just concatenate it with the result of packing the header. That simplifies the format a lot, and in fact you can make it (or rather, a prebuilt `Struct` object) a class attribute: `format = struct.Struct("????i")`.

Comment: Unpacking, likewise, is just a matter of using `unpack_from` to get the header, then using a simple slice to extract the rest for the payload.

Comment: Already had it written up before I noticed you also made `unpack` a class method, so I spent a while debating whether to post or not.

Comment: Nothing wrong with posting similar implementations as long as you've got something to add.

Comment: You answered the question; I'm just contributing some off-topic code review :)

Comment: The class method implementation makes a lot of sense and actually made what a class method is in Python click for me. Thanks a lot for your help. @Kevin

Answer (score 4):

A few notes:

1. You can pre-create a `Struct` object for packing and unpacking the header
2. The payload is easier to pack and unpack by itself, separately from the header.
   It can be appended to a packed header and extracted from a packet using slicing.
3. `unpack` should be a class method that takes a `bytes` object and returns
    an instance of `Packet`.
4. Making this a dataclass avoids having to write a lot of boilerplate for the `__init__` method.

---

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import ClassVar
import struct

@dataclass
class Packet:

    header : ClassVar[struct.Struct] = struct.Struct('????i')
    payload: str
    syn: bool = False
    fin: bool = False
    reset: bool = False
    has_opt: bool = False
    ack: int = 0

    def pack(self):
        return self.header.pack(
                   self.syn, 
                   self.fin,
                   self.reset,
                   self.has_opt,
                   self.ack
               ) + self.payload.encode('utf-8')

    @classmethod
    def unpack(cls, data: bytes):
        payload = data[cls.header.size]
        syn, fin, reset, has_opt, ack = cls.header.unpack_from(data)
        return Packet(
                   payload.decode('utf'),
                   syn,
                   fin,
                   reset,
                   has_opt,
                   ack)
```